# Problems installing simplescreenrecorder on debian jessie

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

I've been having some major issues lately trying to install various software either by compiling from source or via apt-get and aptitude.

I keep getting unmet dependancies which result in never-ending loops and run-arounds when I try to fix things. There is no end to it, and I don't know what to do.

The latest of these issues, trying to install `simplescreenrecorder`, gives this output:

```
$ sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libstdc++6 : Breaks: gnote (<= 3.16.2-1) but 3.14.0-1 is to be installed
python3-pyqt4 : Breaks: eric (< 6.0~) but 5.4.5-1 is to be installed
simplescreenrecorder :
Depends: libavcodec-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
Depends: libavformat-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
Depends: libavutil-ffmpeg54 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
Depends: libswscale-ffmpeg3 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
Recommends: simplescreenrecorder-lib but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks,
this may be caused by held packages.
```

If I'm having such issues with Cinnamon, and they cannot be fixed, then what am I supposed to do? Aptitude wants to remove all the packages entirely. Won't that just completely snafu the system to hell?

Here's some info. I have no clue what's important or not. (Once again, the brain things making me *really* foggy.)

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie

$ ps -e | grep tty7
934 tty7     00:17:43 Xorg

$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
lightdm-xsession

$ wmctrl -m
Name: Mutter (Muffin)
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
```

Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A

- DISPLAY SERVER: Xorg 1:7.7+7
- DISPLAY MANAGER: lightdm
- WINDOW MANAGER: Mutter (Muffin)
- DESKTOP ENVIRONMENT: X-Cinnamon
- CPU Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2720QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
- RAM: 8gb

Edit: Also, for some reason the guy who helped me replace Ubuntu on this system with Debian (which I do like much better) installed the X86 Debian when I have the X86_64 intel core i7 processor, which I 64 bit. The info online says 64 bit instruction set.

Comment: Did you add any 3rd party repo (e.g. ppa, multimedia)? Please add your `/etc/apt/sources/list` and files in `/etc/apt/sources/list.d` (if there is any) to your question. Also have you update your system (sudo apt update && aptitude safe-upgrade) before trying to install that package?

Answer (score 1):

The [**`ffmpeg`**](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/ffmpeg) package is available on `jessie-backports` , to install it;

Edit your `sources.list` by adding the following line:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Update and install `ffmpeg` and `qt4-dev-tools`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools
```

Download the source from [here](https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr/) and build your program:

```
git clone https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr/
cd ssr
./configure --without-pulseaudio --without-jack
make -j8
sudo make install
```

Run `ssr` from the terminal throught :

```
simplescreenrecorder
```